# HTML set an image's content to content generated by a server-side script

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

In my html file I have a button which when I press I want to get a captcha image which is generated by a python script and show its contents on a html image.The ideal way I think is to set the url of the html image to the script and from the script to print the image data into base64 but obviously this doesn't work since the image url expects a specific image type.Another not so nice way would had been to use a frame instead of a img tag and on the python script to print an img as shown in the code bellow, this is something I dont want.

So to summarize:
How can I set the content of an html image to what is generated by a server-side script.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="phone_number">
    <input style="width:150;height:30" type="button" name="answer" value="Εμφάνιση αριθμού" onclick="this.parentNode.innerHTML='<img style=width:150 class=phone_img src=get_phone_captcha.py>'" />
</div>
```

**Python**(the bad way):

```
phone_number='699243324'
image = ImageCaptcha(fonts=['captcha/data/DroidSansMono.ttf'])
buf = BytesIO()
image.write(phone_number, buf)

print "<img width=150 src='data:image/png;base64,"+base64.b64encode(buf.getvalue())+"' >";
```

Comment: You can return the base64 encoded content directly to the <img src="[server side url]

Comment: @lastboy , the I am definitely doing something wrong.Do I need to set any special headers to the python script http request? what should I use for Content-Type ? image/png doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `src` should point to an image file, which really means a path on the server that returns image data, but your script is returning html markup with the data embedded in it instead of *just* the image data:

```
print base64.b64encode(buf.getvalue())
```

will only print the data from the generated image, with an extra `\n` which may cause issues, it may or may not be better to just do:

```
import sys

image.write(phone_number, sys.stdout)
```

to directly write the image data to the stdout and send it back to the client.

Comment: That seems to was the problem, changed it to write directly to sys.stdout and it works

Answer (score 1):

`<img src='data:...` needs a string, so you have to do an AJAX-call to your server in your onclick() function. 
    `...innerHTML='<img style=width:150 class=phone_img src="data:image/png....'+ajaxRet+'">'`